# Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ta', but it was: a custom Object object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a basic field input using the following in Javascript/React

```
export default (value, docRef, field, label) => {
  return (
    <div className="pr-4 w-full">
      <input
        className="px-4 py-2 border w-full"
        value={value}
        placeholder={label}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const fs = getFirestore(app);
          setDoc(docRef, { [field]: e.target.value }, { merge: true });
        }}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am populating this field like so:

```
{doctors.map((d) => {
            const ref = doc(getFirestore(app), d.path);
            console.log(ref);
            return (
              <tr key={ref.id}>
                <td className="py-4">
                  {console.log(d.firstName)}
                  <FirestoreFieldInput
                    value={d.firstName}
                    field="firstName"
                    docRef={ref}
                    label="First Name"
                  ></FirestoreFieldInput>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

But anytime I try to edit the input it throws the following error:
Uncaught FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ta', but it was: a custom Object object

and I am unsure why.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error also but my way around it is editing the cloud firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }

}
```